# wait for terminal command to finish in python

Tags: python, command-line, terminal

I have a python script that I can run using the terminal. However, I need to wait until it finishes (outputs two text files) before I can continue. I implemented:

```
command=['python','segment.py','audio.wav','trans.txt','out1.txt','out2.txt']
cmd=subprocess.Popen(command).wait()
```

it does generate out1.txt and out2.txt almost immideatly but they are empty. When I run the command from the terminal I get the correct out1.txt and out2.txt (after a few minutes). Should I use some other operating commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use communicate:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(command)
cmd.communicate()
# Code to be run after execution finished
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `os.system`.  This will wait for the command to finish, and returns the exit status of 0 if it runs successfully.  To get the meaning of other exit statuses, use `os.strerror(exit_status)`.

See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.system and https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.strerror for more help.

Example:

```
os.system('python segment.py audio.wav trans.txt out1.txt out2.txt')
>>> 0
```

Please note that the argument for `os.system` must be of type `str`.